# Reactive Form pattern Validation and form array validation?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular5, angular4-forms

For reactive form validations i observed many tutorials and plunker links
but i am not getting any  site which solves my problem

problem 1: formgroup pattern is
 `[aA-zZ0-9'-]$/)]`(allow no, characters, -,', space special charactes)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
          'name': ['', [Validators.required,
                    Validators.minLength(3),
                    Validators.maxLength(10),
                    Validators.pattern(/[aA-zZ0-9'-]$/)]],

          'phoneNumbers': new FormArray([new FormControl('')])
        });
      }
}
```

for above that please check this plunker link

https://plnkr.co/edit/km7nGR8DjyE4l6tH5JEC?p=preview

Here if you observed name field it's working as per regular expression conditions in some cases

```
**case1-> aa -- not valid(minimum 3 characters),
case2-> aaa@ --not valid(special chararacter)
case3-> aaa@b -- valid(not giving any message)**
```

in above sceanarios case1, 2 is fine if you observe **case3** input even it's not satisfiying regix rule it's not throwing any message
I am not sure that my regix is right, my requirment is `(min-3, max-10, allow no, characters, -,', space special charactes)`

I am trying so many types, but every where i am getting same problem

problem2: How to apply custom validator for form arrays

Please give me best approach which will sutes all general use cases

Thanks in advance

Soumya

Comment: regex problem..check your regex in regex101.com

Comment: can you tell me wright regix

Comment: The regex you are looking for is maybe `^[A-Za-z0-9-' ]+$`

Comment: it's not working

Comment: examples pleasee

Answer (score 1):

Regarding array validation, if you want to validate the size of the array, you can build a custom validation like this:

```
  arrayLengthValidator(minimumLength: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    if (control.value.length < minimumLength) {
      return {'arrayLength': 'array length is invalid'};
    }
    return null;
  }; 
}
```

And then just add to your form like this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', [Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(3),
                Validators.maxLength(10),
                Validators.pattern(/[aA-zZ0-9'-]$/)]],

      'phoneNumbers': this.formBuilder.array([], this.arrayLengthValidator(1))
    });
```

Now if you want to check empty values on array elements, you can use validation as a Directive and add the selector to your input:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, NG_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appEmptyValue]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: EmptyValueDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class EmptyValueDirective implements Validator {

      validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
           return control.value === '' ?  {'emptyValue': 'input value cannot be empty'} : null;
      }

}
```

And on the input:

```
<input type="text" appEmptyValue>
```

Answer (score 0):

For case three the pattern is `/^[a-zA-Z0-9-']*$/` .

For your requirment  (min-3, max-10, allow no, characters, -,', space special charactes) = use this pattern if you don't need @ or $ just remove that `/^[a-zA-Z0-9-' !@#$%^&]*$/`